# How do I get membership selection to appear on the upload screen then go to stripe payment screen in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

here are some images explaining the situation. What would be the next step in getting the pattern selection to appear on the screen?

[image]

---

[image]

So the product is supposed to be a subscription with gives the customer 10 uploads per month when they subscribe depending on the choice they make. its currently using Stripe as payment.

I have turned on paid membership pro, free version. I got everything setup to where its turned on in the Wordpress dashboard but cannot figure out the next step to get it too appear on the website itself on the upload page

Comment: Why have you tagged this as PHP but there is no PHP code snippet that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.